# Как в Task реализовали Wait()?

Tags: c#, .net, tpl

Я сомневаюсь, что `Task.Wait()` внутри имеет цикл `while`. Но как тогда его реализовали? Через хитрые локи?

Comment: Можно ж легко посмотреть самостоятельно на http://sourceof.net

Comment: @VladD, а можно там посмотреть предыдущие версии фреймворков? А то я там только последний вижу

Comment: Не-а, только последний вроде. Но смысл имплементации вроде не должен сильно меняться.

Comment: @VladD, к данной задаче это не относится, просто я не знал про исходники, теперь вот меня интересуют реализации многих вещей, но для версии 4.0

Comment: Ну, можно декомпилировать mscorlib нужной версии рефлектором или ilspy'ем.

Comment: А еще можно почитать у Албахари, вроде...

Comment: Все ожидания выполняются одинаково. Почти уверен, что он просто вызывает метод Monitor.Wait, который в свою очередь использует внутренний неуправляемый метод CLR ObjWait

Comment: @VadimTagil нет, вы ошибаетесь. Класс Task написан в lockfree-стиле, он не использует мониторы.

Comment: [referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/threading/tasks/Task.cs](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/threading/tasks/Task.cs): Wait вызывает InternalWait; InternalWait вызывает SpinThenBlockingWait; SpinThenBlockingWait вызывает (если задача не завершилась в короткий интервал времени) ManualResetEventSlim.Wait; ManualResetEventSlim.Wait вызывает Monitor.Wait

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Я сомневаюсь, что Task.Wait() внутри имеет цикл while.

Открываем [исходники](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/threading/Tasks/Task.cs,1bfe9e19e44f4cfa), читаем и доходим до метода [`SpinThenBlockingWait()`](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/mscorlib/R/1779e153cb1eebc7.html). Как видно даже из названия метода, схема следующая: cначала небольшой [спин](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/mscorlib/system/threading/Tasks/Task.cs.html#b1c8bf867b403050) (фактически тот самый "цикл while") в надежде, что таск завершится. Если не таск не завершился, уход на [ожидание](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/threading/Tasks/Task.cs,3314): на таск вешается продолжение, которое сигнализирует `ManualResetEvent`, и `Wait()` завершится, когда сработает `ManualResetEvent`.

По такой схеме - спин, а потом уход на ожидание - работают многие объекты синхронизации. Спин дешевый, а синхронизация дорогая. Поэтому можно покрутиться некоторое время в ожидании нужного события, особенно если мы предполагаем, что оно имеет немалые шансы скоро наступить, а потом уйти в синхронизацию.

Comment: Что значит "небольшой спин"? мне это слово ни о чем не говорит в данном случае. Можно чуть подробнее? Мне сложно разобраться самому в этом.

Comment: @iRumba я же написал в скобках. Это просто цикл, во время которого код продолжает занимать процессорное время и пытается дождаться нужного события. Цикл обычно делают таким, чтобы он не занял много времени.

Comment: а сколько времени он занимает? Я не понял на чем основано время жизни этого цикла

Comment: @iRumba зависит от разработчика :). Но я бы сказал, что миллисекунды. Цикл завершается, когда происходит одно из двух: закончились все итерации или мы дождались события.